# MongoDB $graphLookup query to get degrees of separation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Mongo graphLookup problem.

I want the num of degrees separation between jerry and superman, the answer should be 2.

In my bi-directional node structure, jerry is connected to lois, louis is connected to superman.

My data

```
{
    "from" : "jerry",
    "to" : "lois"
}
{
    "from" : "lois",
    "to" : "jerry"
}
{
    "from" : "superman",
    "to" : "lois"
}
{
    "from" : "lois",
    "to" : "superman"
}
```

The query below returns 4 documents with **"degreeOfSeparation" : 4**, this represent the bi-directional connections to superman.

```
db.getCollection("connections").aggregate([
    {
        $graphLookup : {
            from: "connections",
            startWith: "$from",
            connectFromField: "from",
            connectToField: "to",
            maxDepth:5,
            as: "connections"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "connections.from": "jerry",
            "connections.to": "superman"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            degreeOfSeparation: { $size: "$connections" }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to get your `"degreeOfSeparation"` `"from": "jerry"` `"to": "superman"` and all of the degrees of separation using `"$graphLookup"`'s `"depthField"`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "from": "jerry"  // from here
    }
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$to",
      connectFromField: "to",
      connectToField: "from",
      depthField: "depth",
      as: "connections"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "allDegsOfSep": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$connections",
              "as": "conn",
              "cond": {"$eq": ["$$conn.to", "superman"]}  // to here
            }
          },
          "as": "toSuperman",
          "in": {
            "$sum": [
              {"$toInt": "$$toSuperman.depth"},
              // +1 zero-based, +1 "to" field
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // maybe doc has target, i.e., degOfSep = 1
    "$set": {
      "allDegsOfSep": {
        "$cond": [
          {"$eq": ["$to", "superman"]},
          {"$concatArrays": [[1], "$allDegsOfSep"]},
          "$allDegsOfSep"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "allDegsOfSep": 1,
      "degreeOfSeparation": {"$min": "$allDegsOfSep"}
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/URc5w9pDvsz).

Output using extended collection:

```json
[
  {
    "allDegsOfSep": [5, 2],
    "degreeOfSeparation": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Am I correct that this query will search for people with the name "jerry" in the collection and then use the $graphLookup operator to follow the "to" field to find the degree of separation to "superman". The result will be a set of documents containing the degree of separation in the "allDegsOfSep" field and the minimum of that set in the "degreeOfSeparation" field.

Comment: I set`from:lois`, I get a nested object that finds multiple degrees of separation with a min of 3, am I missing something on how a 1:1 degree connection works above?  Thx

Comment: @user3524762  You're right, I made an oversight.  I updated the pipeline to handle that case.  Let me know if there are any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

This might works only on level of Grouped nodes

[Mongodb playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X1Ig-Ixufmm)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$to",
      connectFromField: "from",
      connectToField: "from",
      depthField: "connects",
      as: "connections"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          from: "superman"
        },
        {
          $or: [
            {
              "connections.to": "jerry"
            },
            {
              to: "jerry"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      degreeOfSeparation: {
        $size: "$connections"
      }
    }
  }
])
```